# How do I change the location where system restore points are saved?

Tags: windows, system-restore

How can I change the location (drive, path, etc.) where system restore points are saved on Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From everything I have read, the Windows restore points must be stored on the same drive they are taken from, and have to be stored in the "System Volume Information" folder.

So no, it cannot be changed.

[Vista reference](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-performance-maintenance/153682-saving-system-restore-points-another-drive.html)

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yup, appears it is malicious now, removed.